# Docker image pull from nexus repo

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, nexus

I try to pull image from my nexus repository
when i try to pull from nexus working fine, but i want remove path not working

What is solution to use 10.100.23.30:7777/ by default ?

`docker pull 10.100.23.30:7777/test/jdk-17:snapshot-4` - work

`docker pull jdk-17:snapshot-4` - not work

Comment: That isn’t possible, and the docker folks have no plans to make it possible:  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203

Comment: The following is a bit dirty IMO but "works" 1) on your nexus server create a proxy to dockerhub 2) create a docker group containting the previously created dockerhub procy and your private registry 3) configure your docker daemon to use the docker group as a mirror (i.e. set it in the list of `registry-mirrors` inside `daemon.json`)